# Sloppy focus not working after upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mouse, focus

I used sloppy focus in the previous version. Where focus would change from window to window on mouse over, but would not raise any window unless clicked.

I used this a lot when having two windows and was working on both without having to click the other to do something. Or having something full screen and working in a small window, and having the ability to scroll in the full screen app without having to lose the foreground app i was working in.

I edited gconf-editor. apps->metacity->general-> and unchecked auto_raise. even tried to change the delay to higher. and no change.

used gnome-tweak to change from click, mouse, and sloppy. click works as it should. but sloppy and mouse do the exact same thing.

So is there a way to get sloppy to work as it should?

Comment: does no one have anything?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on 12.04 you're probably not using metacity any longer but compiz.  If you using Unity then you are using compiz.  You don't mention though.  To configure compiz install the settings manager `ccsm` and go to general settings.

Additional details can be [found here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2045972).